# VB6: How to get the handle ID of the program giving DDE response

Tags: vb6, dde

I am sending DDE to a program which is not under my control. The program that responds has multiple instances, and all the instances have the same topic name, link, etc. So I'd like to know which instance is responding to my DDE request.

My code is:

```
textBox1.LinkTopic = "MT4|BID"
textBox1.LinkItem = Combo1.Text
textBox1.LinkMode = 1
textBox1.LinkRequest
```

This is in a Timer event firing every millisecond and it works perfectly.

The problem is that any program can give me the DDE response :(

So, I'd like to know which program is giving me the DDE response.
Is it possible the get the app id (handle) of the dde program which is responding?

Comment: Why? What do you want to do? Usually in dde you know which program will respond because you specify the link topic, and presumably you checked the documentation of some other program X and you know it will respond to that topic

Comment: Well, The program that respond has multiple instances. and all the instances have the same topic name, link, etc. And the program is not under my control. So i'd like to know which instance is responding to my DDE request

Comment: OK, I see. Then it's a good question! ... and I'm afraid I don't know the answer! +1 for the question. I'm going to edit the start of your question to include what you've written in that comment, hope that's OK.

Comment: One extra question. What sort of handle are you looking for? Process handle? Windows handle? And **what** are you planning to do with the handle?

Comment: Any handle as long as i can distinguish between the various instances

Comment: @MarkJ, i can update the info according to the handle (or the pid of the instance)

Answer (score 2):

The server will send the window handle in [WM_DDE_ACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648782%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s  wparam parameter. You can [subclass the your main window](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/shell/shchangenotify.htm) with your own window procedure to cache the window handle before calling the old windows procedure.

Edit: Looks like VB creates a hidden DDEMLMom Window that hosts a DDEMLAnsiClient for each conversation. You can use EnumWindows and compare the result of GetWindowThreadProcessId with the result of GetCurrentProcessId to find the top level windows in your own process, then filter by class name to find the DDEMLMom  window. After you get the DDEMLMom window, find the DDEMLAnsiClient via EnumChildWindows.

You can implement a "switch to" feature via [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539%28VS.85%29.aspx) to help the user to identify the source application.

Comment: Subclass code:    OldWindowProc = SetWindowLong( _
        Me.hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC, _
        AddressOf NewWindowProc)

Comment: I get SET_TEXT and GET_TEXT messages but i'm not getting any of the DDE message after subclassing either the main form or the textbox

Comment: DDE messages are sent to the top windows, not textboxes. Try subclass your main window.

Comment: Yes, i subclassed the top window, please look at the code i pasted in the previous comment